# How to parameterize the API base path in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an URL like this:

```
/id/{idnumber}/status
```

In this URL, `/id/{idnumber}` is the API base path, and `/status` is the resource.

I know that OpenAPI (Swagger) allows parameters in paths, like so:

```yaml
paths:
  /id/{number}/status:
```

but this is not what I need, because `/id/{idnumber}` is the base path and not part of the resoruce path.

Is there any way to have a parameter in the base path?

```yaml
host: my.api.com
basePath: /id/{idnumber}   # <---

paths:
  /status:
```

Answer (score 16):

Parameterized base paths are supported in OpenAPI 3.x, using *server variables*:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

servers:
  - url: https://my.api.com/id/{number}
    variables:
      number:
        default: '-1'
```

Note that server variables MUST have a `default` value - it will be used if the client does not supply a value.

For details, see:

- [Server Object](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0.html#server-object) and [Server Variable Object](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0.html#server-variable-object) sections of the the OpenAPI 3.0 Specification
- [API Server and Base URL](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/) on swagger.io

Comment: Can you use /id/{number} as the server url (basePath in swagger 2.0)? our swagger 2.0 just used /id/{number} for basepath so any env like dev/prod/qa would set the base url - does the full qualified domain name (FQDN) have to be defined now in openapi 3.0?

Comment: not supported by postman

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `basePath` allows variables.

For your case, you don't need to use `basePath`. You can simply put /id/{idnumber} in the URL path. For [example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.json#L302):

```
    "/pet/{petId}": {
```

Comment: But my scenario is so obvious that I have to use only basepath variable.I want to know how to do it in Swagger.

Comment: Sorry @Rad4, You just can't use variables in basePath.  You would likely have to use `/id` as your basepath and then just have `{idnumber}/status` as your operation.