# OpenAPI 3 path substitution with openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: spring, templates, parameters, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I would like to generate a java interface with Spring annotations for an OpenAPI 3.0.1 specification in yaml. In particular it is the `@PutMapping` I want to ask about.

I would like as outcome something like:

```
...
public interface MyInterface {
  ...
  @PutMapping(value = "/mypath/a/{parameter1}/b/{parameter2}", ...)
  ResponseEntity<Void> upsertMethod(
      //Here ... signifies other generated annotations and parameters.
      ... @PathVariable("parameter1") String parameter1, 
      ... @PathVariable("parameter2") String parameter2,
      ...
  );
  ...
}
```

I would like to parametrise `myapibasepath` in the yaml file (excerpt below).

```
openapi: 3.0.1
servers:
  - url: https://host.net
paths:
  /{myapibasepath}/a/{parameter1}/b/{parameter2}: #I want to provide myapibasepath at build time.
    put:
      operationId: upsertMethod
      parameters:
        - name: parameter1
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: parameter2
          in: path
          required: true
...
```

It works if I just put in a value for `myapibasepath` in the yaml file, of course. But I would like to specify it externally, for instance as a parameter in the maven pom.xml file.

I can use a `basePath` with a `myapibasepath` parameter and default value in the yaml file and passing the value as `<serverVariableOverrides>myapibasepath=mypath</serverVariableOverrides>` in the pom.xml file as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182063/848850) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297364/848850):

But then I don't see it in the `@PutMapping` of the generated interface file, as it essentially becomes part of the host URI. That just becomes `@PutMapping(value = "/a/{parameter1}/b/{parameter2}", ...)`

Is there any way I can just pass through a value/parameter to be constant at build time? Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The difference with the answers you mentionned is that they define the `basePath` variable in the `servers` section and don't use it explicity in `paths`.

Your YAML should be :

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
servers:
  - url: https://host.net
    variables:
      basePath: mypath-before-pom-substitution
paths:
  /a/{parameter1}/b/{parameter2}: #I want to provide myapibasepath at build time.
    put:
      operationId: upsertMethod
      parameters:
        - name: parameter1
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: parameter2
          in: path
          required: true
...
```

This way the maven plugin will know about the variable `basePath` and will replace it with `mypath`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same but for paths instead of servers? Have a silly use-case where I need to generate different paths depending on if it's test or not

Comment: This is exactly what the YAML will do : generate different paths depending on the basePath variable. For instance, with maven, you will have to provide a value for basePath variable in each profile for each environment.

Comment: It´s an issue in openapi-generator-maven-plugin, if I define the path to substitute as basePath then the generated client will group it together with the host part instead of the path part and will not work as we receive that information at runtime.